# How to let user select any document and upload it to my server

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my application, there is a registration form which contains one field to upload document.

Now I know that `UIImagePickerController` can be used to fetch image/video file and upload it. But how to let user navigate through files and fetch any kind of document and upload it. (For e.g. .pdf, .docx).

There is `UIDocumentPickerViewController` available but that is available for iOS 8 and further and my deployment target is 7.1.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html might be this link helps you.